# How to handle OptimisticLockException in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have OptimisticLockException that as follow this code(Error Code:entity = em.merge(entity);) because of that when user click save button at same time twice from diffrenet browser tab.
**Note:entity.getOid() is not null!**
who can help me...

```
public static synchronized KirKiraciSozlesmeYeniKayitForm kaydet(KirKiraciSozlesmeYeniKayitForm form, EntityManager em) {

    KirKiraciSozlesme entity = new KirKiraciSozlesme();
    UtilInsCore.copyProperties(form, entity);

    if (entity.getOid() == null) {
        Long oid = DBUtil.getSeqNextValue(em, "KIR_KIRACI_SOZLESME_SEQ");
        entity.setOid(oid);
    } 
    entity = em.merge(entity);
    em.flush();
    UtilInsCore.copyProperties(entity, form);

    return form;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i need solution this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is right JPA behavior. 
When user clicks save button first time entities version field increases. So when user clicks save button in second tab versions are different, and JPA generates optimistic lock exception.
What will be the entity state if user change `field1` in first tab and save it and change `field2` in second tab and save it without optimistic exception?
You can inform user that on second time that entity has been changed by another user and reload new entity state or something like that...

Comment: According to my research, that is right JPA behavior.In this situation, i should give message in catch block.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your code as :

```
...
em.lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

     if (entity.getOid() == null) {
            Long oid = DBUtil.getSeqNextValue(em, "KIR_KIRACI_SOZLESME_SEQ");
            entity.setOid(oid);
        } 
        entity = em.merge(entity);

        em.getTransaction().commit();//To unlock the Entity
...
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: why would the user want to do a PESSIMISIC lock when the question is about OPTIMISTIC ?